# Open another program config file C#

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I have program A windows application and program B another windows application. In program B I need to open program A config file. (App.config) I want to open that in a note pad. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h6ak8zt5) method to launch `notepad.exe` and specify the path to the file:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", "c:\path_to_a\app.config");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is wht I wanted

Comment: If this post helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: If I want to open that notepad as read only how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple ,

```
string filename = "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myproject\app.config";
```

Start new process

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe",filename);
```

Comment: Thnx.This is working. If I want to open that notepad as read only how can I do that?